# Scapy Sniff 'iface' attribute data type

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, variable-types

Using scapy 2.4.3 (installed on pip using `"pip install --pre scapy[complete]"`) with Python 3.7.2

Using the sniff function in scapy, what should the data type that goes into the `iface` parameter be? I used the `scapy.all.show_interfaces()` function to list the known interfaces, and this is the output:

```
INDEX  IFACE                                           IP               MAC
13     Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller              169.254.142.162  HewlettP:47:07:dc
10     Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter          169.254.246.19   Azurewav:80:86:ff
7      Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter      192.168.0.7      Azurewav:80:86:ff
-1     [Unknown] Adapter for loopback traffic capture  None             ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I put `"Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"` into the sniff function, there is no `"scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Interface is invalid (no pcap match found) !"` error, so I know that the interface is valid. However, I am receiving this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_invalid'`. If I change the `iface` attribute to `scapy.all.ifaces.dev_from_index(-1)`, then the error is `OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000000002A8`. What does the iface data type have to be for it to be parsed correctly and work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093154/5459467  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58793945/5459467.

You will need to use the `IFACES` util to access the NetworkInterface object rather than its name.

If that doesn't make the trick, make sure you have the latest version npcap installed, try with a different interface (probably not the -1 one).

Answer (score 0):

It is a python `str` , containing the interface name.

Linux:
use the command in the console:  `ip link` for the names

Examples for the value would be `iface = "eth0"` or `iface = "wlan0"`

See docs: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#sniffing

Comment: But a python string doesnt have an "is_invalid" attribute

Comment: windows see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065489/scapy-sniff-doesnt-accept-the-iface-strings?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure it needs an "is_invalid" attribute? Can you try the strings above

Comment: I guess you are using windows, and I cannot really help you with that, mabye try it like here (see how he is using it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734269/scapy-3-way-handshake